# AjaxControlToolkit AsyncUpload Creates New Session on upload completed

Tags: asp.net, ajax, session

I am using the Ajax Control Toolkit 3.5 (The project cannot be upgraded to 4.0). The project also uses Cookieless sessions. This app is reliant on session state pretty heavily.

Whenever I F5 debug the application, it works fine. However, I've deployed the app to IIS7 and a strange behavior happens. Whenever the file is uploaded the input box turns green as expected, but it is killing session state. Rather, it appears to be creating a new session.

I'm not doing anything special. I've inserted the control:

```
<asp:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload1" runat="server" PersistFile="true" Width="220" />
```

And I check the FileBytes on Save. I was thinking there could be some incompatibility with PersistFile but, again, it works fine when debugging.

I greatly appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're saving the file inside the same web application. When IIS detects a certain amount of new files inside the web app (not sure how many anymore) it will restart the application (and thus kill all the sessions).

Suppose you're currently saving the files in a directory called `/files`. Here's what you can do if you still need access to those file through a URL:

1. In IIS create a virtual directory with the name `files`
2. Point the virtual directory to a directory outside of your web app

When you save the files now, they'll still be available on the same URL, but they will be saved outside the web app and your application will not restart

Comment: Thank you. I'm not specifying a save location per se - I just leverage the FileBytes property from my save method (if HasFile is true). I've worked with other control libraries and they use a temporary appdata folder. I don't really see anything like that configured here so I'm not sure how the persistfile upload works in the background.